# For $f:D\subset \Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb R^m$ prove the following are equivalent:

Tags: general-topology, analysis

For $f:D\subset \Bbb R^n \rightarrow  \Bbb R^m$  prove the following are equivalent:

a)$f$ is continuous in $D$

b)If $O\subset \Bbb R^m$$f$ is an open set, then there exists an open set $G\subset \Bbb R^n$ such that $G \cap D=f^{-1}(O)$

c)If $C\subset \Bbb R^m$$f$ is closed set, then there exists a closed set $H\subset \Bbb R^n$ such that $H \cap D=f^{-1}(C)$

I've tried proving that a) implies b), b) implies c) and c) implies a). I already proved that a) and b) imply each other.

However i haven't been able to prove that b) implies c) and c) implies a). What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Since you have $a \iff b$ you might try $b \iff c$. To this end, it might help to remember that $f^{-1}(U^c) = (f^{-1}(U))^c \cap D$ holds for any subset $U \subset \Bbb{R}^m$. So if $U$ is open, then $U^c$ is closed and vice versa.